# Jquery WebSocket stream on multiple browser

Tags: jquery, websocket, live-streaming

I am building a chat application using django channels, from the django channels WebSocket I can send and receive the message with out any problem,

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer

class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("connected", event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("receive", event)

        text = event['text']
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.send',
            'text': text,
        })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected", event)
```

On JQuery part, below is my JQuery WebSocket Try outs

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1/ws/chat/");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log('Connection Established')
    // socket.send("My name is John");
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
if (event.wasClean) {
    console.log('[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}')
} else {
    // e.g. server process killed or network down
    // event.code is usually 1006 in this case
    console.log('[close] Connection died');
}
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('[error] ${error.message}')
};

$('#send-msg').on('click', function () {
    var msg = $("#msg").val();
    console.log(msg)
    socket.send(msg)
});
```

I opened two different browser (Chrome and Chrome Incognito) side by side and opened the console to see the logs, I can see the **Connection Established** log on both browser, when i tried to send message from one browser, the message is received by the same browser, and the message is not received on the other browser, Here how come i stream the data that receive form the server to both the browser. I request you to please guide me some suggestion to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not proficient with django, but In `websocket_receive` instead of `self.send` you need to find a socket connection of another client and send to that object - if you want to send to specific client. Otherwise if you want to broadcast to all there will be other method. but if you do `self.send` it will obviously send back message to original client, which is not expected result.

Comment: I have experience with  `socket.io` but things are pretty same for almost all languages. So, you probably need to maintain list of clients connected in some array, and send message to that socket object. Good luck.